# prevent sonar qube false positive from overwrite

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, false-positive

I have marked some issues on my project lets say in master-branch as false-positive on sonarqube. Now I have less Issues which is pretty nice.

My question is: will this status be there for ever or there are cases where my issues solved as false-positive will be overwritten for example when I do refactoring or when I deploy new feature branch with the same snapshot name? I dont want to solve the same issues again and again.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/branches-faq/#header-3):

> ### What if I mark an Issue "Won't Fix" or "False-Positive" in a branch?
>
> It will be replicated as such when creating a pull request and merging the pull request into the master branch.
>
> If you're using the Reference Branch New Code definition, issues in the reference branch that come from a feature branch automatically inherit their attributes (including "Won't Fix" and "False Positive" resolutions) from the feature branch.

For subsequent analyses the status should be kept, even when refactoring within some limits. The [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/issues/#header-3) says:

> To determine the creation date of an issue, an algorithm is executed during each analysis to determine whether an issue is new or existed previously. This algorithm relies on content hashes (excluding whitespace) for the line the issue is reported on. For multi-line issues, the hash of the first line is used. For each file (after detection of file renaming), the algorithm takes the base list of issues from the previous analysis, and tries to match those issues with the raw issue list reported by the new analysis. The algorithm tries to first match using the strongest evidence, and then falls back to weaker heuristics.
>
> - if the issue is on the same rule, with the same line number and with the same line hash (but not necessarily with the same message) > MATCH
> - detect block move inside file, then if the issue is on the same (moved) line and on the same rule (but not necessarily with the same message) > MATCH
> - on the same rule, with the same message and with the same line hash (but not necessarily with the same line) > MATCH
> - on the same rule, with the same message and with the same line number (but not necessarily with the same line hash) > MATCH
> - on the same rule and with the same line hash (but not the same message and not the same line) > MATCH
> - is there a matching CLOSED issue > MATCH and Reopen
>
> Unmatched "base" issues are closed as fixed.
>
> Unmatched "raw" issues are new.

In particular, when refactoring, if you change line contents on the same line, or move a line without changing its contents, SonarQube should match the issue that already existed and therefore keep your resolution.

This all refers to branch support available in Developer Edition and above. AFAIK there is no issue synchronization between projects.